# Calculate time difference with overlapped time

Tags: c#

Am just trying to find a logic to solve this problem but am stuck.

i have 6 date time column in my db. like below

```
StartDate =  {14/1/2012 11:00:00 AM}
EndDate=     {14/1/2012 11:30:00 AM}

**Break between start and End Date is 30 mins**

StartDate2 = {14/1/2012 11:30:00 AM}
EndDate2=    {14/1/2012 12:30:00 PM}

**Break between start1 and End1 Date is 1hr**

StartDate3 = {14/1/2012 12:00:00 PM}
EndDate3=    {14/1/2012 01:30:00 PM}
**Break between start2 and End2 Date is 1hr is 1hr**
```

Am trying to find the break between each date set and sum up the final.

For eg:

```
StartDate =  {14/1/2012 11:00:00 AM}
EndDate=     {14/1/2012 11:30:00 AM}
```

Break between start and End Date is 30 mins.

But if you seen Start and End Date 2 and three, the time overlapped. so not sure how timespan will help in this scenario.

**The total break between all three timestamp and the sum up should be 2hours 30 mins**

Please some one throw some idea to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> not sure how timespan will help in this scenario.

`TimeSpan` produced by subtracting a later time form an earlier one will be negative. For example,

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 12:20");
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 12:00");
Console.WriteLine(dt2.Subtract(dt1));
```

[prints `-00:20:00`](http://ideone.com/0mEtav).

You can check if the interval is negative to detect overlaps. One way to do it is examining the `Ticks` property for being negative:

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 12:20");
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 12:00");
var diff = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
if (diff.Ticks < 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("An overlap is detected.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, Correct me if am wrong, so i have to check the "TICKS" between all two dates and if there is no negative then i can subtract if not get the negative value and add it back.

Comment: for eg: EndDate2=    {14/1/2012 12:30:00 PM}


StartDate3 = {14/1/2012 12:00:00 PM}

var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(EndDate2);
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse(StartDate3);
var diff = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
if (diff.Ticks < 0)
{
  here get the difference that means -30
   
}

now subtract the time between

(StartDate3 - End date3 )-30 mins.

Is that logic make sense

Comment: @Usher, if you want to check if the start date comes later than the end date, you can simply use `if(startDate > endDate)`. That might make more sense then computing the difference and checking its postive/negative sign.

Comment: @Usher The logic of what to do when there is an overlap is really up to you. One way is to calculate the two diffs first, create a result diff of zero ticks, and selectively add only the diffs that are greater than zero. Essentially, when there's no overlap, your `diff = diff12 + diff23`. If `diff12` is negative, don't add `diff12`. If `diff23` is negative, don't add `diff23`. If both diffs are negative, keep zero as your final result.

Comment: Chris,if my startDate>EndDate then i have to find the difference and subtract from my total hours.